# Enabling Github webhooks for multibranch jobs?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, github

I'm setting up a CI scheme for a few projects, on Jenkins, using the multibranch plugin.
Everything is working pretty nicely, but the obsessive in me always wants a bit more.

Current situation:
The multibranch thingy is working: picks up and builds new branches and PRs. It does so by polling: Every N minutes it polls Github for new branches and branch updates.

I want:
I would very much like to build new pushes on Github Webhook push events and avoid polling. When not dealing with multibranch, it was as simple as checking the `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling` box.
In this context, I would have to add a new trigger to the Jenkinsfile. I assume something like:

```
triggers {
    githubWebhook()
}
```

Currently, my Jenkinsfile is something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image '${REDACTED}/builder:sbt-0.13-jdk-oracle-8'
            args '-v sbt-cache:/root/.sbt/ -v ivy-cache:/root/.ivy2/'
            customWorkspace '/src/'
        }
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                sh "sbt clean coverage test coverageReport coverageAggregate sonar"
            }
        }

        stage('Push snapshot'){
            when {
                not {
                    branch 'master'
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "[DRYRUN] sbt publishSnapshot"
            }
        }

        stage('Push release') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                echo "[DRYRUN] sbt publish"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        changed {
            echo "[DRYRUN] changed build"
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this? Any other approach?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314483/how-to-trigger-multibranch-pipeline-build-with-github-webhook

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official GitHub Branch Source Plugin documentation](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#github-branch-source), the plugin can automatically configure webhooks for you if you have your GitHub API token configured in Jenkins global settings:

> You can change the build configuration to perform the folder
>   computation at different times. The default setting will scan your
>   GitHub repository for changes if it has not received any change
>   notifications from GitHub within the past day. This scan will catch
>   the repositories you’ve added or removed from the managed GitHub
>   repository. You can always force the Folder Computation to run from
>   the GitHub Organization page.
>
> While the build triggers are often enough, you can set up webhooks to
>   automatically trigger builds when changes are pushed to your GitHub
>   repositories. To do this you must have a GitHub login with a token.
>
> 1. Go to the main configuration settings page, Manage Jenkins > Configure System
> 2. In the GitHub Plugin Configuration section, add a server with your credentials
> 3. If you need a token, generate one with the Additional Actions > Convert login to password and token
>
> You can also configure this manually through GitHub itself by
>   registering the URL provided in the help section of the server config.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create a new job in Jenkins ( Github organization ) and configure it to scan all repos and all branches, you can do it by following this [URL](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003015711-GitHub-Webhook-Organization-Folder) 
second, press scan organization from Jenkins, now you will see all repos and all braches which contain Jenkinsfile which contains all your stages and all pipeline stages, check also this [URL](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-Multibranch-Pipeline-and-Organization)